# Call to undefined function mime_content_type()

Tags: php, mime-types, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Using Suite crm 7.9.1 . newbie to suitecrm.

I created a Person Form in Campaigns module . Created successfully . But when i tried to download it , got the below error .

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mime_content_type() in /home/testsite/public_html/download.php:180
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/testsite/public_html/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php(1007):
>   require_once() #1
>   /home/testsite/public_html/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php(458):
>   SugarController->handleEntryPoint() #2
>   /home/testsite/public_html/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php(366):
>   SugarController->process() #3
>   /home/testsite/public_html/include/MVC/SugarApplication.php(108):
>   SugarController->execute() #4
>   /home/testsite/public_html/index.php(53): SugarApplication->execute()
>    #5 {main} thrown in /home/testsite/public_html/download.php on line 180

when i browsed on this error got a solution that to install this extension . I am using PHP 7 .

Adding the extensions to cpanel in live , is it safe .. As it is shared host , does it affects other php projects .

When i executed phpinfo found something about mime_type . below

```
default_mimetype - text/html
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes - ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
```

Answer (score 23):

You need to install `fileinfo` extension in order to use `mime_content_type`. In debian based system you can install it via apt: `apt-get install php-mime-type`

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get the mimeType of a file using mime_content_type() but it was not working.

Here this works for me:

```
$file = $request->file('FILE_NAME_IN_REQUEST');
$mimeType = $file->getClientmimeType();
```